# Calculate Normal Distrubution using Java

Tags: java, statistics, normal-distribution

EDIT:

Actually I realized that what I need is the value of X. Let me make it clearer. Suppose, I know the probability P = 0.95 since I want to use two standard deviations. I know the ranges **P(-500 < x <500)** that means I know y and z , I know the mean and standard deviation as well. If I want to know what will be the value of x which method should I use. I have found one [calculator](http://stattrek.com/Tables/Normal.aspx) doing something like this but could not understand which formula to use.

Original Question:

> I want to calculate normal distribution probability of random variables using Java. Was not sure which formula to use to code to solve a problem like [this](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx#examples). If I know the value of mean and Standard deviation and want to find the probability of being x's value between 2 certain values y and z (P(-500

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: As trashgod said, definitely look at the apache.commons.Math project. It contains a nice statistics package, which shall be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), available in [`org.apache.commons.math.special.Erf`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/special/Erf.html), as discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Applications) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_confidence_intervals).

Addendum: The methods proposed in @Brent Worden's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353678/calculate-normal-distrubution-using-java/6371765#6371765) considerably simplify the solution of such problems. As a concrete example, the code below shows how to solve the [examples](http://stattrek.com/Tables/Normal.aspx#examples) to which you refer. In addition, I found it helpful to compare the definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_confidence_intervals) to the implementation of [`cumulativeProbability()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/NormalDistributionImpl.html#line.184) using [`Erf.erf`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/special/Erf.html). Note also how the implementation of  [`inverseCumulativeProbability()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/NormalDistributionImpl.html#line.220) generalizes the required iterative approach.

```
import org.apache.commons.math.MathException;
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistributionImpl;

/**
 * @see http://stattrek.com/Tables/Normal.aspx#examples
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353678
 */
public class CumulativeProbability {

    private static NormalDistribution d;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MathException {
        // Problem 1; µ = 1000; σ = 100
        d = new NormalDistributionImpl(1000, 100);
        System.out.println(d.cumulativeProbability(1200));
        // Problem 2; µ = 50; σ = 10
        d = new NormalDistributionImpl(50, 10);
        System.out.println(d.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.9));
    }
}
```

Console:

```
0.9772498680518208
62.81551565546365
```

Discussion:

Problem 1. Among devices having a normally distributed lifespan that lasts an average of 1000 hours with a standard deviation of 100 hours, ~97.7% will fail within 1200 hours.

Problem 2. Among people having a normally distributed skill that enables an average of 50 repetitions with a standard deviation of 10 repetitions, an individual can surpass 90% of the population with 63 repetitions.

Comment: As my answer relies on his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353678/calculate-normal-distrubution-using-java/6371765#6371765), I decline the bounty in favor of @Brent Worden. Of course, you can feel free to accept or up-vote my answer, too. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative from [commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/math) is to use its [NormalDistributionImpl](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/NormalDistributionImpl.html):

```
    new org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistributionImpl(mean, std)
        .cumulativeProbability(a, b)
```

This gives P(a ≤ X ≤ b) for X ~ N(mean, std).

From the updated question, it looks like you want to construct confidence intervals.  If so, use the inverseCumulativeProbability method.  It computes the values x for a probability p such that, P(X ≤ x) = p.

Comment: Thanks .. for the suggestion. Suppose if I know the value of probability (since I want to use two standard deviation(where p is 95%)), I know the values if a and b and I would like to know the value of X. What should I do in that case? I apologize if that sounds naive  but I'm not that familiar with this statistical approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create confidence intervals.  If so, use the inverseCumulativeProbability method.

Answer (score 4):

The [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) library developed at CERN supports many statistic functions; also the Normal (aka Gaussian) distribution in [`cern.jet.random.Normal`](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/jet/random/Normal.html).

Comment: +1: The parts I've used were quite a bit nicer than the commons-math equivalents.